# What happened to the Reliquary of the Primes?

Tags: transformers, transformers-prime

At the end of the *Transformers: Prime* series,

> Optimus Prime used the Reliquary of the Primes to trap Unicron's energy form within it, while Unicron's physical form remains in stasis within Earth thanks to the Matrix of Leadership.

The Reliquary has not been seen again after that scene. What happened to it, as well as the being trapped within, after that?

Comment: It began to be contaminated by composites.